# Streaming mp3 files in native browser player

Tags: php, laravel, browser

I'm trying to open an mp3 file in two browsers - Chrome and Firefox using Laravel controller. The problem is that I cannot play this file properly. In Firefox I got the message "No video with supported format and MIME type found" [image]

In Chrome file is able to be opened in the native player, but the player doesn't let me scroll the bar of file progress.

It looks like the browser treats the file as a video file, instead of MP3. I tried to manipulate this by changing headers, but all I could do is download the file. This is the code from the controller used to open the file.

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-length' => Storage::disk('s3')->size($filepath),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="my_file.mp3"',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
    'X-Pad' => 'avoid browser bug',
];
return response()->make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($filepath), 200, $headers);
```

I will be really thankful for any solution.

Comment: try the correct header for a download is Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-file.mp3"

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will be the in the same situation as me. The problem was file codec. In my case it should be MPEG Layer III. In Linux terminal you can check it by command "file [filename.mp3]"